# How to remove double quotes from a pyspark dataframe column using regex

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am creating a dataframe(**df**) from a text file having json data.After creating the data frame looks like this.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|data                                                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|"{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PARC PARQUE","State":"PR"}"        |
|"{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PASEO COSTA DEL SUR","State":"PR"}"|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to get rid of the double quotes from the starting and ending of the column data.So the final dataframe should look like this

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|data                                                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PARC PARQUE","State":"PR"}          |
|{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PASEO COSTA DEL SUR","State":"PR"}  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Below is the code I have written to remove double quotes from starting

```
df = df.withColumn('data1', F.regexp_replace("data",'^\"{\"','{\"'))
```

but I am getting this error

^"{"
^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1957)

Can you please help me to resove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to tweak your regex a bit. There is no need to escape the quotes, but you need to escape the curly brace:

```
df2 = df.withColumn('data1', F.regexp_replace("data",'^"\{"','{"'))

df2.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|data                                                                                |data1                                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|"{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PARC PARQUE","State":"PR"}"        |{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PARC PARQUE","State":"PR"}"        |
|"{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PASEO COSTA DEL SUR","State":"PR"}"|{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PASEO COSTA DEL SUR","State":"PR"}"|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```